# What's a correct reaction to user with a question showing he's hacked?

Tags: discussion

There was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713370/warning-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by-denying), and lot of people commenting about the general "headers already sent" stuff, when the question OP had, to my knowledge, clearly showed that he's been hacked and should wipe his/her site immediately. I added is [as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14713479/365237) but it seems to get lost within peoples comments about the general "headers already sent" responses.

What's the correct way to react? I would think OP should be notified immediately in a case like this. Or should he?

Comment: You commented, *and* answered; what else could you do?

Comment: hm. some comments from the downvoters would be nice.

Comment: Not much else you can do.  You told the OP about the problem and the OP will get notifications of new answers.  It is up to the OP to decide if your answer was the correct one and act on it.

Comment: Downvotes on meta don't mean the same thing as on SO.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't know, that is why I asked. Is there something that should be done, is it a reason to flag for moderator attention or something. If the answer is "nope, that's it", it's fine by me, just wanted to check.

Comment: @eis ... What, "Flag for moderator phone call?" No, it's not a reason to flag the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time an answer or comment is added to ones question he/she will be notified.

You added an answer to the question and this is the way to go. If the OP does not care about the answers to his/her question, then obviously there is nothing you can/should do about it.

BTW if the OP does not react on your answer does not mean he/she did not read it. And the question you refer does not contain *that* much answers and comments that a late answer won't get noticed. It is the 4th answer with no need to browse answer pages.